# How to get milliseconds resolution in Visual C++9.0 without using windows.h or Boost?

Tags: c++, time, timer

I need to calculate running time of codes in millisecond resolution.
The current `clock()` in `time.h` does not work well for time interval less than 10ms.

I read a lot threads here but I have the following limitations:

1. I cannot use C++ 11 features since only Visuall C++ 9.0 compiler avaiable;
2. it works on a Windows platform but I cannot use `windows.h` header file;
3. I cannot use Boost or Qt;

Does `_ftime()` in `<sys/timeb.h>` work better? or any other simple better solution?

what is the resolution related difference between `ftime` and `_ftime`?

Comment: "it works on a Windows platform but I cannot use windows.h header file;" Why not?

Comment: because of conflicts with other headers I have to use

Comment: Then fix your code until you *can* include `<windows.h>`.  If macros like `GetObject`, `GetPort`, `MIN`, or `MAX` are causing problems, just `#undef` them, or use macros like `NOGDI`/`NOMINMAX` to prevent those from being defined.  Use `_WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`.  See [Using the Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. The header I am trying is from Linux by others, I am not very sure why including `windows.h` will cause compile failure. I only want to check the algorithm efficiency in milliseconds, that is why I have this question. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<Windows.h>` for the *implementation*. That's included only in your .cpp file, where it's isolated. In your header, you can use just `long long` to count milliseconds. You don't need any special types there.